# Expansion of product

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I need help expanding product of density function:

$(C-AX_i)$ where C,A are constants and $1 \le i \le n$

For example if I had a Likelihood function $L(\theta)$ something like:

$(\theta-\theta^2 \cdot X_1)(\theta-\theta^2 \cdot X_2)(\theta-\theta^2 \cdot X_3)...(\theta-\theta^2 \cdot X_n)$

Is there a way I can write it that involves a a sample mean. Ultimately I want to find MLE.

Comment: If you want to use MLE it is sufficient to try maximise the logarithm of this product (so you get s sum), since the logarithm is increasing.  Hope it helps